# standforn-core-nlp gem in rails 3 'Could not find JAR file'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the [standford-core-nlp](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) gem with rails 3 and I keep getting the error 'Could not find JAR file (looking in ../standford-core-nlp-full/joda-time.jar).'.  The file is in the location it is looking for.  Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using [stanford-core-nlp](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp) gem and did not have the problem you described.

I put my the contents of **stanford-core-nlp-full** into the **bin** directory of the gem. In order to see where your gems are installed, use the following command:

```
$ gem env
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-16 patchlevel 392) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/george/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/george/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/george/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.7
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/george/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
     - /home/george/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**GEM PATHS** tells you the path. Now put your models into the bin directory of the stanford parser. In my case, it was */home/george/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/stanford-core-nlp-0.5.1/bin/*

If you absolutely want to keep your models apart from the gem, just specify the full path to your models.